# How can I get these two sprite images to bounce across a screen?

Tags: python, pycharm

> I made this python program using pycharm. My goal is for the two sprite images to bounce across the 640x360 screen using its inheritance from the blocks. Although, one of the sprite images seems to bounce repeatedly and never seems to make it past the middle part of the screen. I think the problem is with my conditional statements in my for loop within my refactorcode.py that code the sprites. I tried changing it up but it doesn’t seem to work.

refactorcode.py

```
import pygame
from ball import Ball, Block, Sprite


pygame.init()
screen_width = 640
screen_height = 360
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

backgrounds = [(0,0,0),(128,0,0),(0,128,0),(0,0,128)]
bgindex = 0

balls = [Ball(screen_width // 2, screen_height // 2, 5, 5, 100, 200, 200, 20),
         Ball(screen_width // 4, screen_width // 4, 3, 3, 255, 0, 0, 10),
         Ball(300, 300, 7, 7, 0, 255, 0, 15),
         Ball(400, 400, 2, 2, 0, 0, 255, 25),
         Ball(500, 500, 4, 4, 200, 200, 0, 30),
         Block(300,200,7,4,255,0,0,32,2),
         Block(300,200,7,4,255,0,0,32,30),
         Block(300,200,9,10,255,0,0,5,18),
         Block(300,200,7,2,4,0,0,32,18)]

user_ball_speed = 2

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

sprites = [Sprite(200, 100, 5, 5, "spaceship.png"),
           Sprite(400, 200, 5, 5, "spaceship.png")]

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(backgrounds[bgindex])

    # Move the user ball
    balls[0].vx = 0
    balls[0].vy = 0
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        balls[0].vx = -user_ball_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        balls[0].vx = user_ball_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        balls[0].vy = -user_ball_speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        balls[0].vy = user_ball_speed

    for ball in balls:
        ball.move(screen_width, screen_height)
        ball.render(screen)
        if ball.x == balls[0].x and ball.y == balls[0].y:
            continue

    for sprite in sprites:
        sprite.move(screen_width, screen_height)
        sprite.render(screen)
    if sprite.x < sprite.width / 2:
        sprite.x = sprite.width / 2
        sprite.vx = -sprite.vx
    elif sprite.x > screen_width - sprite.width / 2:
        sprite.x = screen_width - sprite.width / 2
        sprite.vx = -sprite.vx
    if sprite.y < sprite.height / 2:
        sprite.y = sprite.height / 2
        sprite.vy = -sprite.vy
    elif sprite.y > screen_height - sprite.height / 2:
        sprite.y = screen_height - sprite.height / 2
        sprite.vy = -sprite.vy

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

# Clean up Pygame
pygame.quit()
```

ball.py

```
import pygame
from PIL import Image

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, r, g, b, radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b
        self.radius = radius

    def move(self, screen_width, screen_height):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

        if self.x - self.radius < 0:
            self.x = self.radius
            self.vx = -self.vx
            self.r = (self.r + 27) % 255
            self.g = (self.g + 54) % 255
            self.b = (self.b + 81) % 255
        elif self.x + self.radius > screen_width:
            self.x = screen_width - self.radius
            self.vx = -self.vx
            self.r = (self.r + 27) % 255
            self.g = (self.g + 54) % 255
            self.b = (self.b + 81) % 255
        if self.y - self.radius < 0:
            self.y = self.radius
            self.vy = -self.vy
            self.r = (self.r + 27) % 255
            self.g = (self.g + 54) % 255
            self.b = (self.b + 81) % 255
        elif self.y + self.radius > screen_height:
            self.y = screen_height - self.radius
            self.vy = -self.vy
            self.g = (self.g + 54) % 255
            self.b = (self.b + 81) % 255

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (self.r, self.g, self.b), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
class Block:
    def __init__(self,x,y,vx,vy,r,g,b,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def move(self, screen_width, screen_height):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy
        if self.x - self.width < 0:
            self.x = self.width
            self.vx = -self.vx
            self.r = (self.r + 27) % 255
        elif self.x + self.width > screen_width:
            self.x = screen_width - self.width
            self.vx = -self.vx
            self.r = (self.r + 27) % 255
        if self.y - self.height < 0:
            self.y = self.height
            self.vy = -self.vy
            self.g = (self.g + 54) % 255
        elif self.y + self.height > screen_height:
            self.y = screen_height - self.height
            self.vy = -self.vy
            self.b = (self.b + 81) % 255

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (self.r, self.g, self.b), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

# class Sprite(Block):
#     def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy):
#         super().__init__(x, y, vx, vy)
#         self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
#         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
#         self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
#
#     def render(self, screen):
#         screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
class Sprite(Block):
    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, filename):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.width, self.height = self.image.get_rect().size
        super().__init__(x, y, vx, vy, 255, 255, 255, self.width, self.height)

    def move(self, screen_width, screen_height):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

        if self.x < 0:
            self.x = 0
            self.vx = -self.vx
        elif self.x + self.width > screen_width:
            self.x = screen_width - self.width
            self.vx = -self.vx

        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = 0
            self.vy = -self.vy
        elif self.y + self.height > screen_height:
            self.y = screen_height - self.height
            self.vy = -self.vy
    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```